# How to achieve multi threading using Scheduler class in Python 3?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.5

I want the parallel execution of the task using Scheduler class in Python 3.  Please help me with this.

Here is my code.

```
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time)

def print_hello():
    print('Hello')

def print_some_times():
    s.enter(1, 1,print_hello)   
    s.run()
    print_some_times()
```

print_some_times()

When I run this code it is showing error.
"RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object".
Also I want to run another task using above code.

Comment: It sounds like you can Schedule tasks that run in a parallel thread/process. Your question is pretty vague though. Do you have some sample code?

Comment: I made the changes in my post. Please check it.

Comment: Your s.enter should have `print_hello` instead of `print_some_times`. Otherwise you have infinite recursion.

Comment: I made the changes you mentioned but again it is showing the same error. "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object". I want to keep running the print_hello method without this error.

Comment: Can you update the question to reflect the current code.

Comment: I made the changes in the code.

Comment: Now you end your method with `print_some_times`, of course  that is going to be called recursively.

Comment: Then how it could be possible to keep running print_hello method. I want to keep running print_hello method.

Comment: Help me with issue so that I can keep running the print_hello method without this error  "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object".

Comment: I'm not sure why your first attempt gave you a recursion error. https://paste.pound-python.org/show/MF2kTfo0W73mY6H84LpR/ that repeatedly schedules.